# Delphi XE8: MemoryStream is filled with junk

Tags: delphi, memorystream, delphi-xe8

```
IdFTP_Main.Get('test.ini',MemoryStream);
MemoryStream.Read(Buffer,MemoryStream.Size);
SetString(TempStatus, PChar(MemoryStream.Memory), MemoryStream.Size div SizeOf(WideChar));
```

*test.ini* contains a short, plain text string. The memory size in *MemoryStream.Size* says 8, which is correct. The content of *TempString* is over a hundred control characters. All help appreciated.

Edit: This code produces the correct file, but requires me to write a copy, which isn't secure:

```
IdFTP_Main.Get('test.ini',MemoryStream);
MemoryStream.Position := 0;
MemoryStream.SaveToFile('./test.ini');
```

Comment: What encoding is the file? Is it UTF-16LE with no BOM. Why do you read into Buffer?

Comment: Probably going to be cleaner to use a string stream with the correct encoding.

Comment: The file is a text file in Linux.

Comment: So how is it encoded. You seem to believe it's UTF-16LE encoded but that seems unlikely. I'd think UTF-8 more likely.

Comment: Regarding security, there is none. Writing to file doesn't lower your security levels. If the attacker can read the file, they can read the memory in your program.

Answer (score 2):

You are treating the stream as though it is UTF-16LE encoded. I suspect that's not the case. You need to determine the encoding. Then use a string stream like this:

```
var
  Stream: TStringStream;
  Str: string
....
Stream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
try
  IdFTP_Main.Get('test.ini', Stream);
  Str := Stream.DataString;
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

Or a bytes stream like this:

```
var
  Stream: TBytesStream;
  Str: string
....
Stream := TBytesStream.Create;
try
  IdFTP_Main.Get('test.ini', Stream);
  Str := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Stream.Bytes, 0, Stream.Size);
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

I've guessed at an encoding. You'll need to substitute the correct encoding.

The call to the stream's `Read` method makes no sense in this situation. I've just ignored that.

We can't see how you configured the `TIdFTP` object. Is `TransferType` set correctly? In order for you to debug this further, use the bytes stream code above and dump the bytes that are downloaded. Check that they match your expectation.

Comment: StringStream got me this text: 'ໜI'#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0'⥠À'#0#0#0#0'ֹҰ'#2#1#0#9#0'IsPressed'#0'r'#0'ֹҰ'#2#1#0#$B#0'IsMouseOver'#0'ֹ'#1#0#7#0'躰ָ軐ָ軰ָ輐ָ輰ָ轐ָ轰ָֹҰ'#2#1#0#$B#0'IsMouseOver'#0'ֹҰ'#2#1#0#$B#0'IsMouseOver'#0'ֹҰ'#2#1#0#9#0'IsPressed'#0'r'#0'ֹҰ'#2#1#0#9#0'IsPressed'#0'r'#0'ֹҰ'#2#1#0#$B#0'IsMouseOver'#0'ֹҰ'#2#1#0#9#0'IsPressed'#0'r'#0'ֹȘ'#$008C#$DA00'䋽耀䅙둸¹'#0#0' 䊣'#$DA00'䋽倀䊾'#0#0'ֹ즰'#$008D'澈ু'#$FFFF#$FFFF#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0'ּֹ즰'#$008D'Õ'#$FFFF#$FFFF#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0'ֹҰ'#2#1#0#$B#0'REST STREAM'#0'ֹҰ'#2#1#0#$A#0'SITE MKDIR'#0#$0A0D'ֹҰ'#2#1#0#$B#0'LANG en-US*'#0'ֹȘ'

Comment: You've still not addressed the issue of encoding. Do you understand what a text encoding is? What are the bytes downloaded in the byte stream variant? Do they match the encoding you use? Does this file have a BOM?

Comment: ByteStrem got me this text:
'䕤B'#0#0#4#0#$FDE9#0#8#0#0#0#0#0'➀ɆRR数ɉ'#0#0#2#0#0#0#0#0'➀ɆR䙀Ɇ'#0#0#0#$FF00#0#0#0#0#0#0'➀ɆR䙀Ɇ'#1#0#$FFFF#$FFFF#0'㾀'#0#0#0#0'➀ɆﯔR'#0'䅀꤬ɇ'#0#0'p氀ɂ'#0#0'➀ɆҰ'#2#1#0#5#0'thumb'#0's'#0'➀Ɇᘘ'#$0081#0#0'ഐȽ'#$A#0#1#0#0#0#0#0'➀ɆR䗀Ɇ'#0#0#0#$FF00#0#0#0#0#0#0'➀ɆR䗀Ɇ'#1#0#$FFFF#$FFFF#0'㾀'#0#0#0#0'➀ɆҰ'#2#1#0#5#0'arrow'#0#0#0'➀Ɇ'#$0A80'I'#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0'畡瑬➀ɆE䤫`$'#0'ヸո'#$1BF8'ձ'#0#0#0#0'➀ɆҰ'#2#1#0#4#0'text'#0'§'#0#0'➀ɆҰ'#2#1#0#4#0'fill'#0#0#0#0'➀ɆҰ'#2#1#0#7#0'content'#0'➀Ɇ'#$D7C4'd'#0#0#0#0#0#0'蹘ɉ'#0#0#0#0'➀Ɇ'#$0A80'I배Ⱥ锚'#0#0#0'ꀀ'#0#0#0#0#0'➀Ɇ迴d誰d蝘ɉ'#0#0#1#0#0#0#0#0'➀Ɇ迴d誰

Comment: David, I don't know what the source system encoding is. I don't have command line access for the system.

Comment: That's not a byte array. That's text. Some encoding implied. What are the first 8 bytes, say, in hex. Read them into a bytes stream. But we are moving away from the question. The code in my answer is accurate. The rest is down to you.

Comment: What's more, you said you had 8 bytes. You showed a lot more than 8 bytes worth.

Comment: Source has 8 bytes:^100^200

Comment: Regarding your edit, it's clear that you think this is a code issue but in fact it is a text encoding issue. Once you understand that you'll start making progress. Start by listing those 8 bytes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau FWIW, look at this edit (http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32450486/4) I restored the index/size args to GetString because Bytes can be larger than Stream.Size. I think I've got this right?

Comment: If this is an encoding issue, why does the SavetoFile method produce the exact string?

Comment: Because the text editor works out the correct encoding. What is the encoding? Have you worked it out yet? Can you list these 8 bytes?

Comment: @CharlesBarouch: Because it uses the same encoding for reading and writing. But what are those 8 bytes? Can't be too hard to examine them in the debugger.

Comment: @Rudy that's not quite right. No encodings are used when reading or writing a memory stream. It's just binary. The text editor that the asker uses decodes the binary to text.

Comment: FWIW, the StringStream text in your comment looks like pure unused memory (actually, it looks like part of an executable or dcu). But do you really think 8 bytes produce so much junk?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you are right, I forgot to take into account that `TBytesStream` allocates the `Bytes` memory in deltas to reduce the number of reallocations during writes. The `Size` is the actual number of bytes written, and can be less than the `Capacity`.

Comment: @David: you are perfectly right. Haven't had any coffee yet. <g>

Comment: @CharlesBarouch Are you going to supply those 8 first bytes in the TBytesStream as requested? We are all eagerly waiting! :)

Comment: Once again, the 8 bytes are ^100^200. The carets are shift-6, not a control mark.

Comment: Those aren't bytes. Those are characters. We are looking for 8 numbers in the range 00 to ff.

Comment: @Charles You said earlier that those characters are the *source*, or content of 'test.ini'. We want to know the 8 first *bytes* in the *TBytesStream* immediately after the call to `IdFTP_Main.Get('test.ini', Stream);`. And also let us know what `Stream.Size` is.

Comment: Tom, scroll up. It's in the comments already. It says 8 bytes, but I'm getting hundreds.

Comment: Why can't you show us these 8 bytes? We want 8 numbers in the range 0 to 255.

Comment: @Charles Well, then I can only conclude that Davids conversion of stream bytes to a string works perfectly, and you don't have a problem anymore. Cheers! Regarding 'getting hundreds', that must be something you do wrong, but you don't want help from us.